# How to integrate AWS App Runner with Cognito

Tags: amazon-app-runner

We have containerised applications which we want to host using AWS App Runner. At the same time we want to integrate these applications using AWS Cognito. Like API Gateway authorizer is there any mechanism in App Runner that can handle security of the API Services.

I dont want to introduce a costly AWS Service like APIGateway simply for this cognito integration purpose when App Runner is already creating publicly accessible endpoint to the service.

Comment: Did you have any luck with finding a solution?  I've been hunting around for a while and not come up with much either.

Comment: Why don't you use the api from within the python code? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/python_3_cognito-identity-provider_code_examples.html